# docker build - groupadd: command not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Hi have recently started writing Dockerfile From amazonlinux:latest , i can't seem to figure out why groupadd commnd wont work. I have 2 versions , it works in the first one and it doesnt in the 2nd one. The only difference in the 2nd is I added few more packages to be installed in the yum command.

### Dockerfile_v1 - this works

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum install -y   shadow-utils.x86_64 && \
    yum -y update; yum clean all && \
    rm -fr /var/cache/yum
RUN groupadd -g 10001 test
ADD init /opt/init
CMD /opt/init/start.sh
```

### docker build -t test:v1 .

```
[+] Building 0.7s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 259B                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest                                                                                                                                     0.3s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest@sha256:85c8f169ab712d0c5f3fc6616b851b9b9ad0f895daf465fa1bcc95185697bf31                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 56B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN yum install -y   shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update; yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum                                                                                0.0s
 => [3/4] RUN groupadd -g 10001 test                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => [4/4] ADD init /opt/init                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:0d3c36470209a665c52cd51285036d99d598ce07ad90815706d0c25ecfef5e54                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test:v1
```

### Dockerfile_v2 - this doesnt work - the only addition being added glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 to yum install

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 && \
    yum -y update; yum clean all && \
    rm -fr /var/cache/yum
RUN groupadd -g 10001 test
ADD init /opt/init
CMD /opt/init/start.sh
```

### docker build -t test:v2 .

```
[+] Building 0.9s (7/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 294B                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest                                                                                                                                     0.6s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest@sha256:85c8f169ab712d0c5f3fc6616b851b9b9ad0f895daf465fa1bcc95185697bf31                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 56B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update; yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [3/4] RUN groupadd -g 10001 test                                                                                                                                                                0.3s
------
 > [3/4] RUN groupadd -g 10001 test:
#0 0.268 /bin/sh: line 1: groupadd: command not found
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |         rm -fr /var/cache/yum
   7 |
   8 | >>> RUN groupadd -g 10001 test
   9 |
  10 |     ADD init /opt/init
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c groupadd -g 10001 test" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

This is cut down version of my actual Dockerfile but this shows the issues well. Please let me know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your `yum install` command interactively:

```
$ docker run -it --rm amazonlinux:latest bash
bash-5.2# yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64
[...]
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Sun Mar 19 13:07:58 2023.
No match for argument: glibc.i686
Package libstdc++-11.3.1-4.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: libstdc++.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

The install command fails, which means it doesn't install the `shadowutils` package, which means that your image won't have the `groupadd` command.

It looks like `amazonlinux` doesn't include the `i686` architecture packages.

---

When you're debugging this sort of problem, in addition to just starting up a container and running the command interactively, you can also add `--progress=plain` to the `docker build` command line to see the output of commands as they run:

```
$ docker build --no-cache  --progress=plain .
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 236B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest
#4 CACHED

#5 [2/2] RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update; yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum
#5 1.482 Amazon Linux 2023 repository                    9.8 MB/s |  11 MB     00:01
#5 2.894 Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sun Mar 19 13:10:36 2023.
#5 3.097 No match for argument: glibc.i686
#5 3.099 Package libstdc++-11.3.1-4.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64 is already installed.
#5 3.101 No match for argument: libstdc++.i686
#5 3.106 Error: Unable to find a match: glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
#5 3.204 9 files removed
#5 DONE 3.3s
```

---

Lastly, the reason your `docker build` wasn't failing was because you chose to use `;` instead of `&&` to connect commands in your `RUN` statement. If instead of this:

```
RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 && \
    yum -y update; yum clean all && \
    rm -fr /var/cache/yum
```

You wrote this:

```
RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 && \
    yum -y update && yum clean all && \
    rm -fr /var/cache/yum
```

Then the problem would have been much more obvious; the build would have failed like this:

```
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update && yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum                                                3.1s
------
 > [2/2] RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update && yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum:
#0 1.350 Amazon Linux 2023 repository                     11 MB/s |  11 MB     00:01
#0 2.761 Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sun Mar 19 13:12:40 2023.
#0 2.968 No match for argument: glibc.i686
#0 2.969 Package libstdc++-11.3.1-4.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64 is already installed.
#0 2.971 No match for argument: libstdc++.i686
#0 2.977 Error: Unable to find a match: glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM amazonlinux:latest
   2 | >>> RUN yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 && \
   3 | >>>     yum -y update && yum clean all && \
   4 | >>>     rm -fr /var/cache/yum
   5 |     #RUN groupadd -g 10001 test
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yum install -y  glibc.i686 libstdc++ libstdc++.i686 shadow-utils.x86_64 &&     yum -y update && yum clean all &&     rm -fr /var/cache/yum" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```